# Sollten wir Fragen zur Übersetzung von sinnlosen Begriffen / Sätzen in der Ausgangssprache beantworten?

Tags: discussion, translation

Heute bin ich über diese Frage "gestolpert":

- [Difference Between “Keine Ahnung” and “Ich Weiß nicht”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43445/difference-between-keine-ahnung-and-ich-wei%C3%9F-nicht)

Der Fragesteller hat die eigentliche Fragestellung bereits in der Frage korrekt beantwortet (alle Hervorhebungen ff sind von mir):

> They both roughly mean **I do not know**.
>
> **Keine Ahnung** literally translated is **"No Idea"**

Aber der folgende Diskurs über die *"wörtliche Übersetzung"* macht überhaupt keinen Sinn mehr:

> **Ich weiß nicht** litterally translated is **"I white not"** or "I do not know"?
>
> What are the different uses between them(What are each used for)?
>
> and if you could, explain how **"I white not"** became "I do not know".

In der Ausgangssprache (Englisch) macht ***"I white not"*** schlicht keinen Sinn, und ist bestenfalls als *"Küchenenglisch"* zu werten.

Man könnte sich über die subtilen Unterschiede von

> > Keine Ahnung

und

> > ich weiss(ß) nicht

in einer Antwort auslassen ([wie aktuell versucht](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/43450/28897)):
[image]

Aber ich weiss nicht so recht (kein Wortspiel hier), ob die Frage (auf Grund der falschen Prämisse) überhaupt Sinn macht, und für zukünftige Recherchen nützlich sein könnte.

Das Ganze scheint möglicherweise auf einer falschen Rückübersetzung von Google Translate zu beruhen:

- ["I white not" => "Ich weiß nicht"](https://translate.google.de/#en/de/I%20white%20not)

In der anderen Richtung (Deutsch -> Englisch) liefert Google Translate das korrekte Resultat:

- ["Ich weiss(ß) nicht => I do not know"](https://translate.google.de/#de/en/Ich%20wei%C3%9F%20nicht)

Ich glaube nicht, dass diese Frage wirklich eine Antwort verdient. Zumal ein wenig experimentieren mit Google Translate die eindeutig richtige Antwort liefert.
Die sogenannte *wörtliche* (Wort für Wort) Übersetzung macht schlicht keinen Sinn.

Comment: related: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/655/how-to-handle-typos-that-are-significant-in-respect-to-why-the-question-came-up

Comment: @Zoe "I white not" is complete nonsense in english, that's the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that on the interpretation of some dictionary entries similar questions may arise. They can even be interesting when we are asked for help if any of possible translations fits to a given context.

However in this case there is a simple error from confusing a verb and an adjective or noun which makes this question trivial, and not a good fit for our site (similar to [questions from an obvious typo](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/655/how-to-handle-typos-that-are-significant-in-respect-to-why-the-question-came-up)).

I therefore suggest we close such questions as *off topic* with the reason that we [cannot replace a dictionary](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1315/let-s-change-general-references-to-databaseshttp://).